# Phonegap facebook plugin: various issues with android

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to integrate Phonegap 3.1 with phonegap-facebook-plugin, to make my application able to login with facebook:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

After various searches I found a way to make it work with last version of phonegap, but I'm having 2 main issues:

1) I really don't understand how to configure the "Native Android App" on facebook developer panel, in particular the "Class Name".

Information I found online are a bit confusing. I tried:

- com.facebook.LoginActivity
- *my.app.main.activity*
- com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect

With both of them I receive this error in the logcat:

> Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.AttributionIdProvider

Even if this error is thrown, facebook login works, but:

2) FB.init returns status unknown even if I'm already logged and, when I call FB.login, I receive:

> You already authorized *appname*.

It's a bit frustrating that the app user have to confirm authorization everytime he opens the app...

I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is interested, I finally resolved leaving the facebook connect plugin and using [facegap](https://github.com/studiosoton/faceGap)

It's incredibly simple to integrate.

EDIT:

example:

```
$(document).FaceGap({
    app_id      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    scope       : 'user_photos',
    host        : 'https://yourdomain.com', //App Domain ( Facebook Developer ).
    onLogin     : function (event)
    {
        if (event.message == "Success")
        {
            alert("LOGIN WORKED!");
        }
   },
    onLogout    : function (event) {
        if (event.status === 1)
        {
            alert("LOGOUT!");
        }
    }
});
```

Important: the `host` parameter must be a **valid** URL in your app domain (the one you set in the facebook app configuration). It could be also a blank page, it will be never be loaded, but needs to be a working url, in order to make facegap work.

I also created a [fork](https://github.com/ProGM/faceGap) with a bug fix and a new function (feed functionality):

Comment: Hi, What to specify in App domain. I don't want to redirect on any website as Phonegap app only in local not on server. Please help.

Comment: @ProGM how were you able to make facegap work? I got a 404 error after logging in Facebook. I'm sure my FB settings are correct as I'm using it in our site already. Can you share your solution?

Comment: @vonv. I changed my answer adding some details, take a look ;)

Comment: Thanks ProGM. Although I resorted to using a different plugin that works the first time.

Comment: Hi, i am facing error in when i run your code "message> code:191 message:redirect_uri isn't absolute URI. Check RFC 3986 " kindly help me out. Kindly help me setting a domain please

Comment: Please add some code... It seems you added a wrong domain name when setting up facegap

Comment: @ProGM how can i logout from facebook on my custom button click ? can u help me out

Comment: that's not a native facebook plugin