# Android Phonegap getting Unfortunately <app> has stopped after installing facebook connect plugin

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing an `android phonegap` app with 'Facebook Connect' plugin.

This is the documentation and plugin page that I have used;
[phonegap-facebook-plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin)

After installing the plugin, when the app launch and trigger the fb login function, it gets "Unfortunatly  has stopped" message and crashes.

I have installed this before without issues. This time doesn't work well.

I am using `Cordova. 3.3.1-0.1.2` and `Phonegap. 3.3.0-0.19.6`.

Comment: what do you mean by Cordova. 3.3.1-0.1.2 and Phonegap. 3.3.0-0.19.6

Comment: I am having the same problem, using https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get why u mention both cordova and phonegap..

But please check my answer!

Add the below to your config.xml and ensure you place your config.xml in the root folder with your index.html file:

```
 <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
 <param name="APP_ID" value="..." />
<param name="APP_NAME" value="..." />
 </gap:plugin>
```

Add the below to the  of your index.html file and every .html file that you want to access the plugin scripts:

```
 <script scr="phonegap.js"></script>
 <script src="cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script > 
 <script src="facebook-js-sdk.js"></script >
```

Read and follow the documentation located [here](https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/blob/df97806027da5ba54ab94e093c6b3c0f2ec5de5b/README.md). Be sure to pay attention to the paragraph titled "Facebook Requirements and Set-Up".

Once complete, upload your zipped project to build.phonegap.com and wait for your project to be compiled.

Hope it will help you !!

You can refer this SO Question' answer also.! [Phonegap facebook plugin: various issues with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786585/phonegap-facebook-plugin-various-issues-with-android)

Comment: Thank you! for quick response. :).

I didn't added that config.xml changes.
I'll try with this and let you know.

Comment: same as previous. :(.
I have did those changes and check all the instructions again. so far can't find any mistake. hv no idea what to do next.